Authentication scheme subscription gets lost on deployment of Apex applications
In our Oracle Apex applications we use custom authentication schemes. The schemes on test environment and production differ a little bit so we have an application 100 on each environment which barely changes and only contains the authentication scheme masters for the specific environment. All other application subscribe to these authentication scheme masters.
In the past when I deployed applications to production all I had to do after import was go to application 100 and publish the authentication schemes. So all the authentication schemes were updated to the production version.
But now when I import applications the connection to the master schemes gets lost. Apex shows:

Subscribed From : Nonexistent Master


Subscription Status: Could not determine, needs refresh

I have to unsubscribe and resubscribe in each authentication scheme for all imported applications. Which is much more work than just hitting publish once.
Unfortunately I do not know if this came with an Apex upgrade or any other change. We are currently on Apex 24.1.3.

There were some changes in 24.1.3 in the behaviour of subscriptions, that probably has something to do with the behaviour you are experiencing. I'd ask this question in the official oracle forum - that is monitored by the APEX dev team.

Somehow the behaviour regarding shared component subscriptions must have changed in one of the last releases. On the official oracle forum you can also find some issues with it that should be fixed in the latest version.
However I was only able to fix it by importing the application which contains the master components on command line and setting the offset to zero so that the authentication schemes keep their id:
apex_application_install.set_offset( p_offset => 0 );

